# Menu Custom Data Attributes

Tags: php, menus, css, navigation, html

I'm trying to add a custom data attribute to the `<a>` element. What I'm trying to do is integrate the navigation effect in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/littlesnippets/pen/pjmXvP)

I can do all the CSS but I need to add the HTML part such as below:

```
   <ul class="snip1226">
  <li class="current"><a href="#" data-hover="Home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-hover="About Us">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-hover="Blog">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-hover="Services">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-hover="Products">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-hover="Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

How and where would I add this into WordPress? What would I need to edit to add this HTML functionally?

Thanks,

Harvey

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a custom `data` attributes to the menu that's generated by [`wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) function. You can use the [`nav_menu_link_attributes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_link_attributes/) filter to add the desired attributes to the `<a>` elements.

```
function add_menu_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    $atts['data-hover'] = $atts['title']; // add data-hover attribute

    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_menu_atts', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Okay thank you, I will give that a go. Should adding this work just like how the HTML would work?

Comment: @Harvey that would work as the CodePen example, however please update the **CSS** to match the selectors generated by `wp_nav_menu`. For example: the `current` class to mark the active `<li>` element, in WordPress that would be `current-menu-item`

Comment: Okay that’s what I’ve been doing so will give it a try this morning :)

Comment: Hi, I have added the above code into the functions.php of the child theme which I think is correct? Then I have edited the CSS selector to be '.main-navigation ul.menu' I tired replacing the sector with the current-menu-item but didnt get any of it working

Comment: I have just uploaded the site, sorry if it is slow as its in early development http://derbyshiregas.co.uk/

Comment: Any idea as I am stuck with this now

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
/*
 * Add filter attribute 
 */

add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'modify_walker_data_attr', 10, 4);

function modify_walker_data_attr( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args )
{

    // I use ACF for adding field to a menu item
    // https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-menu-items/
    $data_hover = get_field('data-hover', $item);

    $old = '<a';
    $new = '<a data-hover="'.$data_hover.'" ';

    $item_output = str_replace($old, $new, $item_output);

    return $item_output;
}
```

Comment: `get_field()` is not a WordPress function. It requires the plugin Advanced Custom Fields.

Comment: Yes, as i wrote in my post ;) but you can use whatever you want. Just use print_r(); I use ACF cause i add a text field to my menu item to set the content what i want per item